# SQL: Generate a string from table field and store into another field

Tags: sql

I didn't see any similar questions asked on this topic.
I have to write a sql query for selecting a field from table and then generating a string replacing space with '-' and putting in another field.

[image]

select title field and replace space with '-' and store in slug for all data

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the dtabase you are really using.

Comment: @Rajat, please, a word of advice - my solution changes all data, on and on. Let's say your app inserts a new row; my solution will touch all the other rows. Consider a `select`, as posted by @Eli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rajat Singh. It seems to be simply:

```
update table
set slug = replace(title, ' ', '-')
```

Comment: @Rajat, please, a word of advice - my solution changes all data, on and on. Let's say your app inserts a new row; my solution will touch all the other rows. Consider a `select`, as posted by @Eli

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `REPLACE`.

Use the following to test it

```
SELECT
     ID
    ,Title
    ,REPLACE(title,' ','-') Slug
FROM tableName;
```

and if it is good, use the following to populate the field

```
UPDATE tableName
SET slug = REPLACE(title,' ','-');
```

> Description: `REPLACE` will do exactly as it sounds, replace all instances of a character (or characters) with the replacement string which you provide.
> Here's the link to SQL Server documentation (it's the same for MySQL as well - you have multiple RDBMS tags here): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15